My iterative FFT is slower than my recursive FFT
I've implemented in Python a recursive FFT function and an iterative one. They're both correct (they both pass all unit tests) but, when I plot the complexity curves, I find that the iterative version is slower than the recursive one (the curves are both O(n lg(n)) but the iterative one is shifted up a little). Can you help me identify what, in the following code, is slowing down my iterative FFT method ? Am I using ThreadPoolExecutor wrong ?
def iterative_fft(a: np.array, inverse=False) -> np.array:
    """
    :param a: polynomial in coefficient form
    :param inverse: direct or inverse DFT flag
    :return: DFT(a) in point form
    """
    n = len(a)
    a = bit_reverse_copy(a)

    for s in range(1, int(np.log2(n)) + 1):
        m = 2 ** s
        omega_m = np.exp(2 * np.pi * 1j / m)
        if inverse:
            omega_m **= -1

        def butterfly(k):
            omega = 1
            for j in range(m // 2):
                t = omega * a[k + j + m // 2]
                u = a[k + j]
                a[k + j] = u + t
                a[k + j + m // 2] = u - t
                omega = omega * omega_m

        with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
            executor.map(butterfly, range(0, n, m))

    if inverse:
        a = a / n
    return a

def bit_reverse_copy(a: np.array) -> np.array:
    """

    :param a: polynomial
    :return: reordered array based on index bits reverse
    """
    n = len(a)
    bit_size = int(np.log2(n))
    reversed_a = np.zeros(n, dtype=complex)

    for i in range(n):
        reversed_index = reverse_bits(i, bit_size)
        reversed_a[reversed_index] = a[i]

    return reversed_a


def reverse_bits(n, bit_size):
    """

    :param n: integer
    :param bit_size:  bits used for integer representation
    :return: reversed bit integer
    """
    reverse_n = 0
    for i in range(bit_size):
        reverse_n = (reverse_n << 1) | (n & 1)
        n >>= 1

    return reverse_n




If your code runs without error and produces the correct result then you'll get better feedback on performance, style, technique if you repost your question over at the Code Review StackExchange.

Have you tried profiling your code? That should show you why one code is faster than another https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html
